# Company names list configuration

Tags: apex, community, configuration

I need an advice regaring the following implementation. 
I need to normalize large set of user generated company names for instance 'Derby International LLC', and I need the company name without its extension. In this case the extension is 'LLC'. I use an algorithm which I wrote myself in order to remove the extensions from the name of the company which is working ok. However, in order to get the extesnsions I used a list to store each company extension. Here is the code:

```
List<String> companyExtensionsList = new List<String>(); 
private static void initCompanyExtensions() { 
companyExtensionsList.add('ltd'); 
companyExtensionsList.add('inc'); 
companyExtensionsList.add('group'); 
companyExtensionsList.add('corp'); 
companyExtensionsList.add('llc'); 
companyExtensionsList.add('llp'); 
companyExtensionsList.add('lp'); 
}
```

The company extensions are actually a list of constants.

What I need to know is whether there is a better approach to store the extensions instead of storing the them into a list strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom settings or custom metadata to store this instead of statically storing in code.

Using custom setting or custom metadata admin will have ability to configure these as and when needed as opposed to touching the code for change

Comment: Could you please give a hint or advise how to store company extensions into custom settings or custom metadata. As far as I'm concerned you've mentioned that it can be done by using administration instead of statically storing in code. Could you please let me know how to administer such extensions into my Salesforce?

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4nF0XYx4m80&itct=CBkQpDAYAiITCPT8w7C2v8kCFUR8qgod4xgAHzIGcmVsbWZ1SPCwoKn3ycLFPQ%3D%3D

Comment: Check videos and online resources on custom settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Settings for this.

Go to Setup -> Develop -> Custom Settings and create one (should be of type "List"). You will most likely not even need a field (the default "Name" field should suffice).

Then, from the same menu, click "Manage" and add as many records as suffixes you have.

In your code, then you can do this.

```
 //assumes you used the name field as specified above
  Set<String> suffixes = MyCustomSetting__c.getAll().keyset();

  //Assumes you used another field
  List<MyCustomSetting__c> settings = MyCustomSetting__c.getAll().values();
  Set<String> suffixes = new Set<String>();
  for (MyCustomSetting__c setting : settings) {
    suffixes.add(setting.myCustomField__c);
  }
```